# how the geometry, co-ordinate system defined in modeling?

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi,
i'm newbie to gazebo. right now, i'm stuck at http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_robot&cat=build_robot tutorial(build a simple robot). the problem is, i just cant figure out how the co-ordinate system taken for caster-sphere?where does the exact universal co-ordinate system centre lie?(to define the pose co-ordinates of caster sphere).
please help...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8922/how-the-geometry,-co-ordinate-system-defined-in-modeling?/) by [baiju](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1239/baiju/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In that tutorial, you're making a model which can be placed anywhere in the world, so you don't need to worry about the world coordinates there.

Each pose is described with respect to the parent element. The hierarchy goes: **model > link > visual/collision**. That is, link poses are expressed with respect to the model, visual and collision poses are expressed with respect to the link.

The caster wheel is composed of a `caster_collision` and `caster_visual`, both under the `chassis` link. The chassis origin (the center of the box) is 0.1 m on the Z axis with respect to the model origin. The caster collision and visual are exactly on top of each other. The sphere origin (its center) is -0.15 m in the X axis and -0.05 m in the Z axis from the link origin. If you want to know the caster's pose with respect to the model, just add this to the link's pose and you get [-0.15 0 -0.95 0 0 0].

See [this question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8497/standard-units-of-measure-and-coordinate/) for a bit more information about coordinate conventions in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1